# order of execution in run loop

Tags: objective-c

I am using `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:selector:@selector(loop):repeats:YES]` to create a neverending loop with `-loop()` being called every interval. My viewcontroller also has a `-touchesBegan` to process UITouch's.
Suppose the screen is touched and a UIEvent is fired, does the code in `-touchesBegan` execute first in the run loop or the code in the `-loop` called by NSTimer execute first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained in [this Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW23).

However, it's not that useful. `NSTimer` is not a real-time mechanism, and you can't predict exactly when it fires. It will also depend how often iOS registers touch events, and how often you configure the timer to fire. It would be a very, *very*, **very** bad idea to write a code which depends on these subtleties and features buried deep in the documentation I just cited.

Write code which doesn't depend on what you just asked.